# How to write text to a file using TextLineDataset

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to read text in a file Shakespear.txt line by line using 
tensorflow TextLineDataset. Split the words in a line and write the words in another file txt.txt one word per line. Here is my code

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()
BATCH_SIZE=2
#from tensorflow.keras.model import Sequential
dataset_in_lines=tf.data.TextLineDataset("Shakespear.txt")
dataset=dataset_in_lines.map(lambda string: tf.string_split([string]).values)
with open("txt.txt","w") as f:
    for k in dataset.take(2):
        for x in k:
            f.write("\n".join(x))
```

When i run it it gives the `error: Cannot iterate over a scalar tensor`
in the f.write line. Please help me figure out the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better way, replace `dataset=dataset_in_lines.map(lambda string:tf.string_split([string]).values)` with `tokenizer.tokenize`. The following code achieves the objective(see https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/text for more details)

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
tokenizer = tfds.features.text.Tokenizer()
dataset_in_lines=tf.data.TextLineDataset("Shakespear.txt")
vocabulary_set = set()
for x in dataset_in_lines:
    k=tokenizer.tokenize(x.numpy())
    vocabulary_set.update(k)
with open("txt.txt","w") as f:
    for x in vocabulary_set:
        f.write(x+"\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be helpful if you could share the `shakespear.txt` file, but based on your error, it seems liek it is receiving the tensor not the actual value. 
So, you first need to get the value from tensor `k`, you can use `k.numpy()`.

Replace `for x in k:` with `for x in k.numpy():`

Let us know if it works.

Comment: Shakespear.txt is just a normal  text file nothing special about it. Any text file replicates the error.  if I use x in k.numpy(): I get the error TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found